# Pixelated Java applet on Macbook Pro Retina display

Tags: java, macos, applet, retina-display

I'm using java and acm-imports to draw things in an applet,
and it comes out pixelated on my Macbook Pro Retina display.

I code using Sublime Text, compile and run it directly from the Terminal. My Java version is 1.7.0_65.
Is there any fix for this? Any way to make the image look sharp on Retina display?

Thanks

Comment: Are you drawing lines/shapes or images?

Comment: @whiskeyspider I'm drawing lines and typing words.

Comment: I saw the same behavior and I'm wondering what's the cause.

Comment: With a Retina display, Swing Graphics primitives (for example drawLine) map single-pixel strokes in your source code to two-pixel strokes on the physical display at runtime. I am looking for a way to disable this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906175/is-there-a-way-to-disable-mac-os-retina-scaling-for-a-swing-app